# JS - Duplicate array item and change value in duplicate while in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm looping through a array filled with objects, and when i certain condition is met i want to make a copy of the current item and change a value **only** for the duplicated item.

Something like:

```
while (j--) {
  if (value[j].extended.subcategories[0] === "lorem") {
    value.push(value[j]);
    value[DUPLICATED_ITEM].extended.subcategories[0] = "ipsum";
  }
}
```

I was playing around in jsfiddle and i also tried something like:

```
while (j--) {
  if (value[j].extended.subcategories[0] === "lorem") {
    value[value.length] = value[j];
    value[value.length].extended.subcategories[0] = "ipsum";
  }
}
```

This does add a duplicate but when trying to change a value in the object it's (still) undefined.

---

Small sidenote: while playing with the fiddle, i found another weird interaction that i don't really get. If you do this: https://jsfiddle.net/luffyyyyy/bs1h0qLz/13/. Both array[0] and array[3] get a value of 8 while i just specify array[3] = 8;

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you don't clone duplicated item but rather use same instance.
Since I do not know internal structure of your data I would suggest to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` to clone values which you want to duplicate.

```js
while (j--) {
  if (value[j].extended.subcategories[0] === "lorem") {
    const duplicate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value[j]));
    duplicate.extended.subcategories[0] = "ipsum";
    value.push(duplicate);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS, by pushing value[j] into array or by creating new object with operator "=", it will just copy the pointer to the memory area of the array. Pointers of 2 objects become looking at the same area and when you change 1 of them, you will change both. 
To get rid of this, you can use:

```
Object.assign({}, value[j]);
```

which will create a new are of memory with the same value and pointers will be different.

I've also updated you code snippet, you can check it:

```js
let array = [{name: 'test', value: 1}, {name: 'blala', value: 2}, {name: 'jojo', value: 3}];

let obj = Object.assign({}, array[0]);
obj.value = 8;

array.push(obj);

console.log(array);
```